# Window not movable with full size content view in combination with transparent title bar

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a simple app with the settings below but when I use full size content view in combination with transparent title bar the window is not movable/draggable. I have tried setting `view.window?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true` in `override func viewDidAppear()` but that does not work. What am I missing to make the window work like expected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your view is opaque, because `NSWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground` indicates that window can be moved *by own background*.

In such case you have to subclass used `NSxxxxView` and override `NSView.mouseDownCanMoveWindow` read-only property to return `true`.